# onCreate called before and after onActivityResult

Tags: android, android-activity, android-camera

I try open camera following way:

```
...
    private void runCamera() {
        String storageState = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        if (storageState.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            File imageFile = new File(Singleton.instanse.mPushFilePath);
            mImageFileUri = Uri.fromFile(imageFile);
            intent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                    mImageFileUri);
            startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_RESULT);
    }
...
```

if I run this method run next methods:

```
07-16 19:46:22.264: I/System.out(6875): -onPause
07-16 19:46:26.104: I/System.out(6875): -onStop
```

I make photo, end run next methods:

```
07-16 19:46:41.217: I/System.out(6875): -onDestroy
07-16 19:46:41.284: I/System.out(6875): -onCreate
07-16 19:46:41.291: I/System.out(6875): -onStart
07-16 19:46:41.295: I/System.out(6875): -onActivityResult
07-16 19:46:41.295: I/System.out(6875): -onResume
07-16 19:46:41.295: I/System.out(6875): -onPostResume
07-16 19:46:41.522: I/System.out(6875): -onPause
07-16 19:46:41.522: I/System.out(6875): -onStop
07-16 19:46:41.522: I/System.out(6875): -onDestroy
07-16 19:46:41.604: I/System.out(6875): -onCreate
07-16 19:46:41.612: I/System.out(6875): -onStart
07-16 19:46:41.616: I/System.out(6875): -onResume
07-16 19:46:41.616: I/System.out(6875): -onPostResume
```

Why onDestroy run twiсe? How to fix it?
This problem found in Android 2.2. In Android 2.3.3 onDestroy never called!

Comment: Please use `android-activity` tag instead of `activity` tag :)

Comment: this might be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10411009/activity-killed-oncreate-called-after-taking-picture-via-intent/10411504#10411504

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Actually the camera causes the orientation change in your activity that is why your activity is being destroyed and recreated.

Add this in your manifest file it will prevent the orientation change and your activity will not get destroyed and recreated.

```
<activity
    android:name=".YourActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
</activity>
```

[Activity killed / onCreate called after taking picture via intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10411009/activity-killed-oncreate-called-after-taking-picture-via-intent/10411504#10411504)

Comment: What do you do if you can't force the activity to be in a specific orientation?  I'm running into a similar problem and can't force an orientation...

Comment: I'm running into a similar problem. I have this code in my activity. Launch my camera, but because my activity calls OnCreate before and after the OnActivityResult callback, the image is never seen in the view I put it unless the device is held in Landscape mode before the activity begins.

Comment: This is *not* a solution. If your device has not enough free RAM to keep your activity in memory when starting the camera (it happens…), the issue remains.

Comment: @MarcPlano-Lesay do you have any idea how can that be handled, I wanna keep my activity and call camera intent

Comment: @ParagPawar you have no way to enforce that. Android _will_ get rid of it if the memory is needed. Save your state in `onPause` and restore it in `onResume`.

Answer (score 4):

`onDestroy` is not guaranteed to be called. Make sure you save persistent state in `onPause` rather than `onStop` and `onDestroy`. You should never rely on either `onStop` or `onDestroy` to be called.

Answer (score 1):

onDestroy is not guaranteed to be executed on any android version, if it does you should do something quick and return

also see this [Activity OnDestroy never called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4449955/ondestroy-never-called)