# When I return back to my Activity onCreate is raised instead of onActivityResult?

Tags: android, back, oncreate, start-activity

I have an Activity that opens a new Activity for result like this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(ActDocument.this, ActCustomers.class);
startActivityForResult(i, ActDocument.DIALOG_CUSTOMER);
```

when I press back in the child Activity and return back to the parent Activity `onActivityResult` is called in all of devices correctly but I have fount a device that `onCreate` is called instead of `onActivityResult`.

This device is Samsung Galaxy Tab-P5100 Android 4.0.3. It is strange that I have tested my application on other devices of Samsung Galaxy Tab-P5100 Android 4.0.3 and it was OK but I have problem only in this device.

Why? How can I solve that?

**Update**

I noticed `onDestroy()` of parent Activity is called after opening child Activity on this device.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

most of the time Back button will finish the activity unless you specific override the

> OnBackPressed()

I think your problem is lack of resources, or maybe you have some developer options like kill activty flag or limit background process check this.

**Update**

Go to setting-> developer options unchecked don't keep activities and background process limit set to standard limit.

Comment: How can I check? Why it is OK in all devices except on device?

Comment: I noticed `onDestroy()` of parent Activity is called after opening child Activity on this device.

Comment: go to setting-> developer options unchecked don't keep activities and background process limit set to standart limit

Comment: Yeah ..Thanks  a lot!! This solved my issue too !!!
But how can we detect if user has checked this option in his/her device.??

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the `back` button doesn't finish the Acivity. So, override `onBackPressed`.

Comment: I tested. Nothing changed :(

Comment: @breceivemail sorry. I misread your code. I updated my answer.

Comment: I am doing this. I override onBackPressed. I think it is not related to my question

Comment: Hm. Only one device. Perhaps there are some memory issues. Is the device running a lot of other apps?

Comment: The only thing I can think of, is that Android kills the `ActDocument` activity for whatever reason while in `ActCustomers` activity. Other than that, no idea why it doesn't work.

Comment: I noticed `onDestroy()` of parent Activity is called after opening child Activity on this device.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22313/discussion-between-bart-friederichs-and-breceivemail)