# Activity is getting destroyed while pressing the home button

Tags: android, android-activity, ondestroy

In my application, when I press the home button the activity is going to `onDestroy()`. It suppose to be called `onPause()` method only right?

Why it is happening so?

Comment: Can you add some code?  If you explicitly command onPause (or even onDestroy), then your problem will mostly likely come from that area.  Use the search function.

Comment: Look at these answers: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14195833/779408 http://stackoverflow.com/a/14196279/779408 Maybe you have same problem. Go to setting-> developer options unchecked `Don't keep activities` and `Background process limit` set to standard limit. If `Don't keep activities` is checked, the state of Activities are not kept so when you leave an Activity it is destroyed. Enjoy!

Comment: is the nohistory attribute true for your activity? if so then activity finish will be called

Comment: `android:noHistory` defaults to `false`

Comment: @breceivemail you saved my life !

Comment: @nandeesh Thank you so much for saving my life. But I think `noHistory="true"` doesn't call `finish()`. I checked with printing `isFinishing` in `onPause` and `onStop`, but both of them showed `false`. Did I check incorrectly?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It depends on how much memory your phone has, if your phone does not have very much memory, then it will destroy the activity to free up resources immediately. On new phones, this will not happen because they have plenty of spare memory.

Answer (score 15):

also check that you don't use the android:noHistory flag in your manifest for the Activity

documentation:
android:noHistory
Whether or not the activity should be removed from the activity stack and finished (its finish() method called) when the user navigates away from it and it's no longer visible on screen

Comment: You are absolutely right, but just a quick question: I think `noHistory="true"` doesn't call `finish()`. I checked with printing `isFinishing` in `onPause` and `onStop`, but both of them showed `false`. Is `finish()` not called?

Answer (score 6):

You activity could be destroyed upon pressing the home button if the system is constrained and has determined it needs to free some resources. The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) states that `onDestroy()` can be called if:

> This can happen either because the activity is finishing (someone called finish() on it, or because the system is temporarily destroying this instance of the activity to save space. You can distinguish between these two scenarios with the isFinishing() method.

Additionally, do note that the system can `kill` your program without calling `onDestroy()` after `onStop()` has been called. Therefore, any cleanup/data persistence code should be in either `onPause()` or `onStop()`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it depends on a lot of factors. If you are facing this issue on Android 3.2+ devices, you should add screenSize property to android:configChanges

```
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

Besides, also add android:launchMode="singleTop" to your launcher activity. Do note that you'd need to use Android SDK 15 or above as target, however,  your app will work on older devices as well. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

another thing to check is whether your activity call `finish()` when `onPause()`

Answer (score 1):

Of course may be memory problems, but before that check the manifest file, in the declaration of the activity, if you have "no history" declared (you don't want the activity to remain in the activity stack. Also you may using some flag when you create the activity with an intent. 
Then, most probable answer is the one given by Alex Contour.