# Pressing home button calls onDestroy on parent

Tags: android

I have three activities `Main`, `Item`, and `ItemDetail`

`Item` has `Main` set to Parent in manifest

```
<activity 
  android:name=".Activities.Item"
  android:parentActivityName=".Activities.Main"
/>
```

`ItemDetail` has `Item` set to Parent in manifest

```
<activity 
  android:name=".Activities.ItemDetail"
  android:parentActivityName=".Activities.Item"
/>
```

Here is what the activity flow should look like visually

```
Main > Item > ItemDetail
```

Both `Item` and `ItemDetail` extend from `BaseActivity`

```
public class Item extends BaseActivity { ... }
public class ItemDetail extends BaseActivity { ... }
```

`BaseActivity` displays and enables home button

```
 getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
 getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Now here is the problem: when pressing **BACK** button from `ItemDetail` activity, `Item` is brought to the foreground which is the expected behavior, right? However, when **HOME** button is pressed from `ItemDetail` activity, `Item` activity's `onDestroy` and `onCreate` are called, indicating (obviously) that `Item` activity is being destroyed before being recreated.

My question is why is `Item` activity destroyed and when pressing home button from `ItemDetail` but not back button. This makes no sense to me.

**TL;DR**

My app is crashing when pressing home because I expected `Item` to remain on the activity stack and maintain state, but activity is unexpectedly destroyed resulting in a null pointer error.

**edit**

Yes, I have onSavedInstance state implemented and working, it's just that the saved states is gone, calling this line from `Item` activity's `onCreate` returns true

```
null == savedInstanceState; // returns true
```

Comment: It makes pretty much sens as non foreground Activity may be destroyed at any time

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Acivity is getting destroyed while pressing the home button.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14314252/acivity-is-getting-destroyed-while-pressing-the-home-button)

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't assume any activity remains on the backstack and maintains state.  Instead you should implement onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState properly.  The framework may kill your Activity at any time it isn't foreground.  There's even a developer option setting to help test this, which will close all activities as soon as they're no longer foreground.  I suggest testing your app with this mode every so often.

Comment: I should have mentioned that. I do have onSavedInstance state implemented and working. Configuration changes like screen re-orientation are handle properly when `onDestroy` and `onCreate` are called. It's just there is no saved instance states available when pressing the back button from `ItemDetail` i.e. `null == savedInstanceState` returns true.